# Postgres Timestamp conversion with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timezone

I am trying to use this query I found on the internet to convert timezone, but having a hard time understanding it.

Basically, I want to read a date string from a source file and store it in database in that user's timezone. The database column is of time `timestamp without time zone.`

Let's say user's timezone is known to be`'America/Chicago'` and source file timestamp is `'2018-06-06 05:00:00'`

Now to convert the source datetime to this timezone, I've used:

```
select  (('2018-06-06 05:00:00'::timestamp  AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' ) 
              at time zone 'America/Chicago') as t
```

But, this gives `2018-06-06 00:00:00`, which is incorrect because the time is getting truncated.

If I don't cast the value to timestamp, it gives correct value with GMT offset `2018-06-06 10:00:00+05:30`.

```
select  (('2018-06-06 05:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' ) 
              at time zone 'America/Chicago') as t
```

I'm not sure how to correctly interpret these results and my knowledge about timestamp/timezone is not so good. Can anybody explain how to understand these queries and what is the right way to simply get a value of `2018-06-06 10:00:00`, which I will have to store in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works.  The time is not being truncated.  5:00 a.m. GMT is midnight Chicago time.

But, if you want 10:00 a.m., then I think you have the time zones backwards, and you really want:

```
select (('2018-06-06 05:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'GMT' ) as t
```

This coverts 5:00 a.m. Chicago time to GMT.